PlatformIO - how to use own library files in project folder
I’m using VSCode with PlatformIO, and my application compiles and runs, but my Git repo is missing the Library. I need to move the library files into the project folder, but can’t get it to work.
My library for control of a fan has Fan.cpp & Fan.h, and my test.app contains the line
#include <Fan.h>
The 2 library files are in a shared library (shared_lib) at the same level as the test project as shown in this directory tree:
├── test  
│   ├── ReadMe.md  
│   ├── include  
│   ├── platformio.ini  
│   └── src  
│        └── test.cpp  
├── shared_libs  
│   └── Fan  
│       ├── Fan.cpp  
│       └── Fan.h  

However, the git repository is in the test project, so the library files don’t get saved.
I have tried moving the Fan directory out of shared_libs and in to the 'include' directory one level below test, but the compile fails when it gets to the #include line for Fan.h
fatal error: Fan.h: No such file or directory
How can I resolve this?
My platformio.ini file is
default_envs = esp32
src_dir = src
include_dir = include

[env:esp32]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitc-1
framework = arduino

; Library options
lib_extra_dirs = ../shared_libs
lib_ldf_mode = chain+

If I move the last section (library options) of the platformio.ini file to directly after [platformio] section with no blank line, the compile complains about missing a different file in the shared_libs, one which has always been there and does not need to be in the repository.
